# How to submit and receive forms in raw Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, forms

I'm new to Ruby and I find it extremely difficult to learn anything in Ruby that is not related to Rails.

I wanted to know how I have to proceed to submit an HTML form to a Ruby script and get this data in the server side.

Will it work if I send it through XMLHttpRequest (AJAX)? If yes, how can I send a response to Javascript in JSON format? If not, why?

Assuming that I want to use the POST method, in PHP it would be as following

```
if(count($_POST)>0){ //or, isset($_POST['a_key'])
   //do something
   echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "raw ruby"?  You're trying to receive an HTTP post with just a Ruby script?

Comment: As it sounds like you might be doing more than just simple POSTs, you still might want to [start with frameworks](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/web_app_frameworks), first... Ruby is yet more of a general purpose language whereas PHP has a lot of built-in, web-related functionality out of the box.

Comment: isn't it possible to submit a `<form>` and get the data in a Ruby script? is it just that difficult? i'm impressed (and a bit disappointed, I think I created the wrong expectations)!

Comment: You have the wrong expectations.  Ruby is not that similar to PHP, especially in this area.  You need a server of some kind to get the request into your script.  For Rails, [Rack](http://rack.github.io) is used for this.  If you don't want to use Rails, there are smaller frameworks like [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com) that are lighter weight (still uses Rack though).

Comment: thanks guys.
@NickVeys I read about Mechanize. Do you recommend using Rack instead?

Comment: Mechanize or HTTParty for **using** web sites via Ruby, but you'll need something else to **receive** data.  There are 'ruby http server' examples if you google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby we tend to rely on existing wheels. One that's very popular is [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html), which makes working with a POST request very simple:

```
require 'sinatra'

post '/' do
  # do something here
end
```

To convert something to JSON, use the JSON class:

```
require 'json'

foo = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2}
puts foo.to_json
# >> {"a":1,"b":2}
```

Mix and match as necessary.

> I read about Mechanize.

Mechanize is great when you need to navigate through a website by reading pages, filling in fields and clicking links and buttons. It doesn't do JavaScript and isn't useful when you're trying to handle incoming requests. That's where Sinatra shines.

> Do you recommend using Rack instead?

Rack isn't anything close to Mechanize so there's no comparison. Rack is a middle-layer inside a HTTPd, and is very powerful. You *could* use Rack to build out a web server, but it's not as convenient as something like Sinatra. Both Sinatra and Rails sit on top of Rack, which should tell you something about what Rack does, and whether you want to try writing to it directly.

Comment: oh that looks quite simple. But in this first code example, when you import Sinatra, is it when you receive the data? How would you refer to a post parameter?

Comment: fair enough. I like your answer! thank you very much :)

Comment: Sinatra is very easy to use, and a great tool for throwing together interfaces to services you want to expose. I use it a lot, and always enjoy how fast it allows me to create a service on the web.

Comment: I also highly recommend learning to use [Haml](http://haml.info/). It will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: I'm giving it a look. Seems to be very useful. thank you http://haml.info/tutorial.html